# Accessibility for html elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I've been searching around for a more definitive answer but it seems that what I've uncovered has been out of date or the forum has a dispute as to the correct answer.

I'm building a react web app without bootstrap. **Where is it appropriate to use alt vs title vs aria-label properties?**

*From what I've gathered:

a and Link tags use title and aria-label

img tags use alt and aria-label

button tags use title

Comment: I think you need to explain better. For example an `img` just needs an `alt` attribute, why are you using `aria-label` for that? What is the use case you are thinking requires that? `link` tags - they aren't HTML elements you can interact with? `title` is next to useless nowadays so not sure what info you need for that as it isn't recommended normally. `<button>` tags don't need a `title`, what is your use case for that? I would suggest you refine the question to just one element and or property you want an explanation on then we can help.

Comment: Hmm, well that's the information I gathered from the many threads on accessibility, to use those properties for those tags.
Essentially I want to educate myself and make sure that my website buttons, links and images are accessibility friendly.

Comment: For buttons the text is the important bit, everything is built into `<button>`. The only time you need anything else is if you use an `<img>` (use `alt` attribute) or icon in the button (use `aria-label`). For links - same principle, text is preferable, img use `alt` attribute, icon use `aria-label`. Images, use `alt` attribute, research `figcaption` for additional information. Loads of info on https://a11yproject.com/ or learn WCAG at https://www.wuhcag.com/wcag-checklist/. Sadly the question is just a bit too broad to give you everything. Try MDN for each element / tag as they give good info

Comment: Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute *aria-label* is used in the context of **interactive elements** that can be clicked or manipulated in some ways.
This is especially the case for links, buttons, and form elements, as well as elements that have been made artificially focusable with tabindex=0.

If the element you are trying to label **isn't interactive, not focusable**, you are better recommanded to use *visually hidden text* instead of aria-label.
The former is much more universally recoghized, while the later isn't guaranteed to be read in the case of a non-interactive element.

The *alt* attribute is specific for **images**, i.e. `<img>` tag, as well as image buttons `<input type="image">`.
Everywhere else, it doesn't exist. It is usable both for interactive and non-interactive images.
Avoid using alt and aria-label on the same focusable element to avoid any possibility that one is announced but not the other (in general one totally replaces the other).

The *title* attribute is less recommanded nowadays, because its support is extremely variable depending on the running screen reader and browser, as well as on which element it is used.
It still often works at many places though, especially links and form elements.
Again, avoid using both title and aria-label on the same element to avoid any possibility that one is announced but not the other (in general one totally replaces the other).